# SQL Grouping By Counts

Tags: sql, confluence

I have a table from a database. It's pretty simple: it has a PK, let's call it WS_NUM, and a second value that can have duplicates called DEPT.

I want to get the count of all the WS_NUM that correspond to each DEPT (which I can do).

But, then I want to take the results of that which might look something like

```
-------------
|  1  | This  |
|  1  | That  |
|  2  | His   |
|  2  | Hers  |
|  7  | Mine  |
|  7  | Yours |
|  7  | OURS  |
 -------------
```

And have it group by the Count so you would get something like:

```
 -----------
| 1 | This  |
|   | That  |
 -----------
 -----------
| 2 | His   |
|   | Hers  |
 -----------
 -----------
|   | Mine  |
| 7 | Yours |
|   | OURS  |
 -----------
```

Is this even possible I know I could do this with LINQ and some extra C# pretty easily but this is for a Confluence SQL Query so I'm really limited by what I can do.

Comment: What flavor of database will this be executed on? e.g. Postgres, MySQL

Comment: Visually merging consecutive numbers is a display-layer job and should not be done in SQL.  It should be done in the UI layer.

Comment: @xathien - Pretty sure it's SQL (Backend to a Track-It System)

Comment: @DStanley - I came to the same conclusion myself before I posted. With Confluence and our current plugins i'm not sure if I have something that would do that. Plus it's been years since i REALLY got nose deep into a good SQL query so this was more of a hail mary just to see if it COULD be pulled off with what i'm limited by. But i'm at peace if the answer is no.

Thanks for weighing in!

Comment: @TofuBug: I gathered that much. :) Knowing what kind of SQL database will help design a query that can do this. I'll give you a rough outline of what can be done as an answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what kind of SQL DB is backing Confluence, I can't give an exact answer, but I can give a general idea.

With an initial query that looks like

```
SELECT COUNT(WS_NUM) as WS_COUNT, DEPT FROM WOSSNAME GROUP BY DEPT
```

You can perform that query as a subselect that will aggregate the departments into a single column. A MySQL example using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT WS_COUNT, GROUP_CONCAT(DEPT SEPARATOR ',') FROM (SELECT COUNT(WS_NUM) as WS_COUNT, DEPT FROM WOSSNAME GROUP BY DEPT) as subselect GROUP BY WS_COUNT;
```

Or a Postgres example using `array_agg`:

```
SELECT WS_COUNT, array_agg(DEPT) FROM (SELECT COUNT(WS_NUM) as WS_COUNT, DEPT FROM WOSSNAME GROUP BY DEPT) as subselect GROUP BY WS_COUNT;
```

Both `array_agg` and `GROUP_CONCAT` are specific to the Postgres and MySQL, respectively, which is why it's important to know what you're querying.